# Oracle database won't uninstall

Tags: database, oracle11g

I, unfortunately, installed Oracle database 11g release 2 Enterprise/Standard Edition on my portable hard drive. Problem is, it will only run through CLI. I want to uninstall it but somehow, I cannot do it the conventional way (Universal installer->deinstall products->remove). Is there any other way?

Comment: You should just be able to manually delete all the files. Remove the data directories, Oracle home, oraInventory, etc. A few difference between Windows/Linux installs, which did you use?

Comment: @JacobBarnes I used windows installation.

Comment: Why doesn't the conventional way work? You haven't said what happens or what error(s) you get.

Comment: @AlexPoole when i select home 1 and click remove, it opens a warning dialog box that says i should run a command to deinstall. I tried running the command but its still installed.

Comment: What command does it tell you to run? What response do you get? What do the logs say? Did you run that as an administrator? (Please edit the question to add additional details).